# how many unit balls are needed to cover a unit sphere (1-dense set on a unit sphere)

Tags: measure-theory, computational-geometry, concentration-of-measure

There is an exercise in a geometry textbook to prove that "any $1$-dense set in the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ has at least $\frac{1}{2}e^{n/8}$ points". It is supposed to be easy.

A set $T$ is $\epsilon$-dense on the sphere if $\left(\forall x\in S^{n-1}\right)\left(\exists y\in T\right)\ d(x, y)\leq\epsilon$.

It will probably use the measure contcentration theorem for the sphere. That is, for your convinience: Let $A\subseteq S^{n-1}$ be a measurable set with $\mu(A)\geq\frac12$, let $A_t$ denote the $t$-neighbourhood of $A_t=\left\{x\in S^{n-1} : d(x,A)\leq t \right\}$. Then $1-\mu(A_t)\leq 2e^{-t^2n/2}$.

The spheric measure $\mu(X)$ for $X\subseteq S^{n-1}$ is defined as the fraction of the volume of the unit ball occupied by the points connecting $X$ to $0$, that is $$\mu(X)=\frac{\lambda\left(\{tx : x\in X, 0\leq t\leq1 \}\right)}{\lambda(B^n)}$$

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Possible due to the ambiguity of the metric, I can't make the constants work   right. But the idea should be: let $A$ be the northern hemisphere. Take $t$ such that $A_t$ is the complement of $\{x: d(x,s)\le 1\}$ where $s$ is the South Pole. The MCT gives you an exponentially small upper bound on the volume of the spherical cap $\{x: d(x,s)\le 1\}$. It follows that to cover the sphere, we need at least a certain number of such caps (exponentially large).

Comment: @how-about-a-nice-big-cup-of Thank you. Had it been an answer I would have accepted that. I would use the euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$ because then the result holds for arclength too. I tried to compute it but got a better result than was asked, which is somehow suspicious.

Comment: Why don't you post your solution as an answer, so others can take a look at it?

Comment: @how-about-a-nice-big-cup-of I added it to the question. Is there a major step missing?

Comment: How do you see that the distance from pole to $A_{1/2}$ is greater than $1$?

Comment: @how-about-a-nice-big-cup-of Added that as a lemma.

Comment: Looks good, but you should check the source of your concentration of measure inequality. In [these notes](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~harry/teaching/pdf/lecture13.pdf) i see the factor of $2$ in front of exponential. If this settles the issue, please move the answer from question to the answer box.

Comment: @how-about-a-nice-big-cup-of  And you are of course right. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have $p$ the north pole ($p_n=1$, $p_1,\ldots,p_{n-1}=0$) and $A$ the southern hemisphere $A=\{x\in S^{n-1}:x_n\leq0\}$. Then in euclidean metric $d(A_{1/2},p)>1$ thus we know that the pole covers at most the area of $1-\mu(A_{1/2})$. By the MCT we have $1-\mu(A_{1/2})\leq 2e^{-n/8}$ - upper bound on the area covered by one point. It follows that we need at least $\frac{1}{2e^{-n/8}}=\frac 1 2e^{n/8}$ points.

Thanks @how-about-a-nice-big-cup-of for the tip.

---

Lemma: $d(A_{1/2},p)>1$

Proof: Let's have a point $x\in S^{n-1}$ such that $x\in A_{1/2}$. We will show that $d(x,p)\ > 1$.

W.l.o.g. $x=(x_1,0,\ldots,0,x_n)$ (from the symmetry). And $x$ is on the northern hemisphere ($x_n\geq0$).

From $x\in S^{n-1}$ we have $x_1^2+x_n^2=1$.

From $x\in A_{1/2}$ we know that the distance of $x$ from the equator ($x_n$=0) is at most $\frac 1 2$. The nearest point on the equator is $y=(1,0,\ldots,0)$, then $$\left(\frac 1 2\right)^2 \geq (d(y,x))^2=(x_1-1)^2+x_n^2=(1-x_1)^2+(1-x_1^2)=2-2x_1$$
so we have $x_1\geq \frac 7 8$. And equivalently $x_n=\sqrt{1-x_1^2}\leq\sqrt{1-\left(\frac 7 8\right)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{8}$.

At last we compute the distance to the pole:
$$(d(x,p))^2=x_1^2+(x_n-1)^2=(1-x_n^2)+(x_n-1)^2=2-2x_n\geq2-2\frac{\sqrt{15}}{8}>1$$ $\square$